# Can't see my mouse in certain os

Tags: mouse, antergos, solus

I literally just installed Solus Linux and right now, I can't see where my mouse is. I can still click on things (if I'm lucky enough to), but it's very hard to tell where it is. Also the actual icon is stuck on the top left part of the screen.

This happened when I was trying to install Solus and also in my attempts to install Antergos, but it never occurred when I was installing Manjaro.

Yes, I have restarted my computer, unplugged and re-plugged my mouse, and tried a different mouse with no change. I don't know why this happened in Antergos and Solus but not Manjaro, or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing this in terminal :

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```